# Asset Catalog Compiler Options missing

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode5

I just switched a project over to using Asset Catalogs for icons and launch images. It appears that something has gotten borked, though, because the assets are not getting built into the app. I can't be sure, but I suspect the problem is related to the fact that the **Asset Catalog Compiler – Options** panel is missing from my project/target Build Settings. In new apps, or other apps that I have switched over, once the target is using an Asset Catalog that panel will appear. For this project, when I enable an catalog (under the General tab), I get `ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME` and `ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_LAUNCHIMAGE_NAME`, but they are listed under **User-Defined** settings, and the other settings that should appear in the 
Asset Catalog Compiler are missing.

Anyone have any ideas how to coerce Xcode to find these settings?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Evidently the **Build Settings** won't parse asset-related settings correctly unless there is an asset in the **Copy Bundle Resources** of the target. Simple solution, but something I overlooked, since migrating to an asset catalog for icons and launch images apparently doesn't always add itself to the target automatically.

Comment: Indeed - just spent some minutes searching for the option in the Build Settings in a number of projects in my Xcode workspace that did not user Asset Catalogs.. just the projects with actual catalog will have that particular section in the **Build Settings**. D'oh!

Comment: How did you add the "Asset Catalog Compiler - Options" into your build settings to get the catalogs to work?  I am having the same issue you had.

Comment: Do you have an asset catalog including in Copy Bundle Resources?

Comment: To add it to the copy bundle resources, select the "Images.xcassets" folder (or whatever it's named) in the left panel, and then make sure the Target Membership is checked against the target you're building