# Error asset catalog compiler error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, assets, xcasset

I finished an app and after i finished uploading the app Icon images It doesn't run  and i had this error:

[image: asset catalog compiler error distill failed unknown reason]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode error : Distill failed for unknown reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20580968/xcode-error-distill-failed-for-unknown-reasons)

Answer (score 8):

More simple way is - click right mouse button on the error (on "Distill failed for unknown reasons") and select "**Reveal in Log**".

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU. I have been wracking my brain over this after multiple failed archive attempts. This immediately solved my problem

Comment: @OshadhaPunchihewa It was a problem with icons files (in my case), please look at the your log for details.

Answer (score 4):

This may be an issue with an image that is saved with the PNG extension that is actually NOT a png file (frequently this happens when using "save as" on a PSD and naming it with .png while forgetting to actually convert the file).

This has been answered before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20580968/xcode-error-distill-failed-for-unknown-reasons).

Answer (score 2):

Ok so here is how i fixed it , i removed all the images and uploaded them one by one until i found this one image , that was .png but there was something wrong with it so i re-did it in photoshop , and poof the error was gone .

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57504566/2537455).

*(Note: I had no .psd as .png, etc.)*