# Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error Distill failed for unknown reasons. 1264

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

is there anyway to solve this issue 
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Distill failed for unknown reasons. Sophia.iOS  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets    1264

note that this issue appear after latest version of xcode and osx catalaina
also im useing a vertual osx

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1s8OT.jpg)

Comment: Try to find the images to replace or delete which are shown in your error message(like `files:///Users/.../Icon1024.png` and so on)

Comment: I tried before i post the issue ...

Comment: did you alter your Assets.xcassets ? you could refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20580968/xcode-error-distill-failed-for-unknown-reasons

Comment: Sorted and i post the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all who try to help but.....
this issue solved when i update the OSX and xcode with latest versions