# Images.xcassets:1:1: Distill failed for unknown reasons

Tags: swift

when create any new project i am facing this Xcode error
please any help
xcode 11.3
macOS catalina 10.15 beta(19a487m)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVz6x.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode error : Distill failed for unknown reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20580968/xcode-error-distill-failed-for-unknown-reasons)

Answer (score 0):

Format you icon from [appicon.co](https://appicon.co/#image-sets) then drag @2x and 3x@ icon at a time at Xcode images.xcassets.

Comment: the problem still exist