# Assets folder error "Distill failed for unknown reasons" Xcode 11

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have updated my Xcode to latest version xcode'11 and get the error "Distill failed for unknown reasons" in my assets folder. what should I do to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

I have faced same issue. I solved it by 
go to the Target/Build Phases / Copy bundle resources
Remove Assets.xcassets 
clean project and again add Assets.xcassets in copy bundle resources
then build project.

Answer (score 0):

> You might have migrated from a normal project to use an image.catalog.
>   So you can definitely try to copy the bundle resource like launch
>   images. It is so because migrating to an asset catalog for icons and
>   launch images apparently doesn't always add itself to the target
>   automatically.
>
> You can find more on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145089/asset-catalog-compiler-options-missing/19148032#19148032) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20483713/asset-catalog-compiler-error/20502937#20502937).
>
> I hope that helps.

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20580968/xcode-error-distill-failed-for-unknown-reasons?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
what do you me mean by "migrated from a normal project to use an image.catalog"

Comment: @MAHMOUDOMARA please see the second link

Answer (score 0):

Some of your images are not copied properly Go to Project -> target -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources 
and check which file is missing copy the file here and that will work.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was not enough to update Xcode, I also had to update my Mac OS to Catalina.  Everything else did not work.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I 'm using Catalina  version 10.15 Beta (19A487m) which is latest. Could you tell me which version do you use.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by installing a clean copy of Catalina.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after upgrade xcode11. MacOS beta upgrade solved my problem.

My currrent versions: 
XCode 11.2.1 (11B500) and Catalina 10.15.1 (19B88)

You can see [here](https://developer.apple.com/support/install-beta/) how to install OS beta

Hope to help other users who encounter this problem ...